# When running appium test on a real device it failed with Error: xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

There are so many related issues but nothing solved my issue.
I can run the simulator without any issue, but when running on a real device I get this error

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
```

I have done the [manual config](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/#full-manual-configuration) already.
My environments are :

```
appium - Version 1.17.1-beta.0
Xcode - Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
```

So far I have tried with appium versions:

```
1.13.0
1.15.0
1.15.1
1.17.0
1.17.0
```

I was able to build the WebDriverAgent to the device without any issue.

[The log](https://pastebin.com/hD8YgQKP)

If I run

```
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<udid>' test
```

I get the following result.

```
Testing failed:
WebDriverAgentRunner:
    WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app (379) encountered an error (Failed to load the test bundle. (Underlying error: The bundle “WebDriverAgentRunner” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources. dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/14851F2A-8FB2-4845-9A20-410C9463CEB3/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/WebDriverAgentRunner): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/14851F2A-8FB2-4845-9A20-410C9463CEB3/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/WebDriverAgentRunner: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/14851F2A-8FB2-4845-9A20-410C9463CEB3/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/WebDriverAgentRunner'
```

))

Comment: ios version 13.3.1

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by updating xcode to the latest.
This was posted [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504#issuecomment-592767041)